# How can i add css style tag in django template

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I'm trying to style my HTML code but it's not working properly I tried to add the style  tag inside the load static tag and also I tried to add block mycss tag

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}


{% load static %}



<style>

    .divider:after,
    .divider:before {
    content: "";
    flex: 1;
    height: 1px;
    background: #eee;
}
</style>



{% block content%}


<section class="vh-100">
    <div class="container py-5 h-100">
      <div class="row d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center h-100">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-7 col-xl-6">
          <img src="https://mdbcdn.b-cdn.net/img/Photos/new-templates/bootstrap-login-form/draw2.svg"
            class="img-fluid" alt="Phone image">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-7 col-lg-5 col-xl-5 offset-xl-1">
          <form>
            <!-- Email input -->
            <div class="form-outline mb-4">
              <input type="email" id="form1Example13" class="form-control form-control-lg" />
              <label class="form-label" for="form1Example13">Email address</label>
            </div>
 <!-- Submit button -->
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Sign in</button>
  
            <div class="divider d-flex align-items-center my-4">
              <p class="text-center fw-bold mx-3 mb-0 text-muted">OR</p>
            </div>
  
            <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" style="background-color: #3b5998" href="#!"
              role="button">
              <i class="fab fa-facebook-f me-2"></i>Continue with Facebook
            </a>
            <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" style="background-color: #55acee" href="#!"
              role="button">
              <i class="fab fa-twitter me-2"></i>Continue with Twitter</a>
  
         </form>
```

I'm trying to style my HTML code but its not working properly I didn't add my full  HTML code anyone please help me to solve this

Comment: Hello @Pycoder, If you're extending your html tamplate from **base.html** then you can put css there or you can create a block in **base.html** for css inside ***head*** tag eg. `<head>{% block css %} {% endblock %}</head>` and then use it like this `{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}{% block css %}{% endblock %}` in your other template.

Comment: If you need detail explanation with code then let me know.

Comment: bro i tried <head> {% block css%} css styling code {% endblock%} </head> and ten i use {% extends 'base.html' %} {% load static %}{% block content %} html code {% endblock %}  but it shows an error like {% extends 'base.html' %} must be the first tag in the template.

Comment: then I tried  
{% extends 'base.html' %}
<head>
{% block css %}

<style>

    .divider:after,
    .divider:before {
    content: "";
    flex: 1;
    height: 1px;
    background: #eee;
    }

    
</style>


{% endblock %}
</head>


{% load static %}


{% block content%}
  but not working css

Comment: Hi @Pycoder please provide your **base.html** and check my answer

Answer (score 0):

but as i see you not use your divider class in you code
if you want to style div elements you should use this

```
<style>
div{
bla bla
}
</style>
```

Comment: `{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% load static %}


<style>
div{
    .divider:after,
    .divider:before {
    content: "";
    flex: 1;
    height: 1px;
    background: #eee;
    }
}
    
    
</style>


{% block content%}
`     Not working

Answer (score 0):

[***`Template inheritance`***](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/templates/language/#id1) works the same way class inheritance works in [***OOP***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming). So if you want to inherit **base.html** and want to update some parts, then you block that part that you want to update, and then in another template you can use the same block to add new content. For example, if you want to update **CSS** in **layout.html**, which is extending from **base.html**

**base.html**

```html
<html>
  <head>
   {% block css %}
    <style>
      /* add your css */
    </style>
   {% endblock %}
  </head>
 <body>
 {% block content %}
  <h1>Base</h1>
 {% endblock %}
 </body>
</html>
```

**layout.html**

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block css %}
 <style>
   /* add your css */
 </style>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
 <h1>Layout</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

So when you visit **base.html** you'll see **"Base"** and if you visit **layout.html** you'll see **"Layout"** with their own stylesheet applied.